# How to rename many2many widgets in product form in odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9

How to rename the many2many widgets in product form route_ids many2many widget . i want to rename the field name in many2many widgets

Comment: Do you mind clarifying. In the hypothetical example `field_name = fields.Many2many('your.model','relation_1_id','relation_2_id,string='Field Name')` with xml `<field name='field_name'/>` what aspect of this hypothetical are you trying to change?

Comment: actually i want to change in many2many widgets with checkboxes i need to change the checkbox name in product form Routes

Comment: For my above example would you expect the checkbox to have the label `field_name` or `Field Name`. My guess is that the `string` attribute for the field would be what appears as the checkbox label. I have not tried this.

Comment: Its the display_name on the record